# Inheritance with enums and EnumMaps in Java for sound pack creation

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a sound pack in Java for an Android app that is hot-swappable via settings. The part I'm stuck on is the ability to force new sound packs to adhere to a contract and implement every existing Enum. For example:

```
public enum AudioFX {
    ERROR,
    SUCCESS,
    NOT_FINISHED,
    TIMED_OUT,
    ITEM_NOT_SELECTED
}
```

I'm mapping these values to their Raw resources in Android like so:

```
EnumMap<AudioFX,Integer VoicePack = new EnumMap<>(AudioFX.class);
VoicePack.put(AudioFX.ERROR, R.raw.voice_error);
VoicePack.put(AudioFX.SUCCESS, R.raw.voice_success);
VoicePack.put(AudioFX.NOT_FINISHED, R.raw.voice_not_finished);
```

Unfortunately if I create a new EnumMap for a different sound pack, I can't think of a way to insure that every Enum is accounted for at compile time. What can I do to enforce this constraint? Is there a different pattern that I can use that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some static code analysis tool could help here.

What will definitely work: a generic unit test. You can always query an enum for its constants, and then you "only" have to make sure that each of your EnumMap instances is checked via a generic unit test.

Meaning: you could write a small helper utility that checks if all enum constants of enum X are showing up within an EnumMap instance.